# Solutions to the linear nonuniform transport equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics, transport-equation

This is a bit of a soft question, however, the concept is still bugging me in my studies.

If we consider the following proposition: Solutions to the linear transport equation are constant along characteristic curves.

How can I interpret this geometrically, let alone, in general?

Recall: the linear nonuniform transport equation is as follows

$$U_t + c(x)U_x=0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand this statement, we need to determine the characteristic curves. For this purpose, we solve $x'(t) = c(x(t))$ with $x(0)=x_0$. The solutions of this differential equation are the curves $t\mapsto x(t)$ along which $U$ is constantly equal to its initial value $U(x_0,0)$. Therefore, the characteristic curves are the paths along which information propagates. Note that

- if $c$ is constant, then the characteristics are straight parallel lines with slope $c$ in the $x$-$t$ plane;
- if $c$ is piecewise constant, then the characteristics are piecewise linear and parallel;
- if $c$ is linear, then the characteristics are exponentials, etc.